# Exporting constant macros as constexpr values in C++20 module

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, c++20, c++-modules

I am currently playing with C++20 modules, in order to modernize our company code base.

Suppose you want to write a C++ module to export the content of a C library that uses `#define` to declare numerical or string constants. For example, imagine you want to create a `Windows` module with all the content of `<Windows.h>`.

So assume we have an existing third-party library header `SuperLib.h` that contains this:

```
#pragma once
struct super_lib_type {int field;};
extern void super_lib_function(int a);
#define SUPER_LIB_CONSTANT 42
```

Now we write a C++ module like that:

```
export module SuperLib;
export
{
#include <SuperLib.h>
}
```

The `super_lib_function` function and `super_lib_type` type will be successfully exported in the module. But obviously **not** `SUPER_LIB_CONSTANT` constant, since macros are by design never exported to C++20 modules.

To fix this, it will be great if we could have the equivalent of that code:

```
export module SuperLib;
export
{
#include <SuperLib.h>
}
#undef SUPER_LIB_CONSTANT 
export constexpr auto SUPER_LIB_CONSTANT = 42;
```

But without having to hard code the value `42` in the module file.
I tried to write a macro to do that. This one kind of works:

```
#define EXPORT(name) export constexpr auto SL_##name = name;
EXPORT(SUPER_LIB_CONSTANT)
```

It will export a constant `SL_SUPER_LIB_CONSTANT`. But this approach has the inconvenience to require a prefix, or a suffix, in the symbol name. For compatibility with existing code, it would be great if the exported name is the same as the original macro.

I thought I could solve the problem by splitting the original macro name into 2 pieces.
Something like that:

```
#define CONCAT(prefix,suffix) prefix##suffix
#define EXPORT(prefix,suffix) export constexpr auto CONCAT(prefix,suffix) = prefix##suffix;
EXPORT(SUPER_LIB_,CONSTANT)
```

But this generates the invalid code `export auto constexpr 42 = 42;` after preprocessing.

Still, I have the impression that it is possible to write a two arguments macro to fulfill the need. And maybe even a single argument macro.

Comment: About *"But this approach has the inconvenience to require a prefix, or a suffix, in the symbol name"*, some may argue that wrapping those constant in a namespace (like `SL::SUPER_LIB_CONSTANT`) might be a better choice.

Comment: @Bob__ Possibly. But I think this doesn't solve the issue, as in this case `SUPER_LIB_CONSTANT` is still a single token for the preprocessor which is not aware of namespaces.

Comment: Perhaps something like this `constexpr auto foo = SUPER_LIB_CONSTANT;` `#undef SUPER_LIB_CONSTANT` `export constexpr auto SUPER_LIB_CONSTANT = foo;`

Comment: @n.m. Yes, I also came to the conclusion this is as close as it could be. The only problem is that this is very unhandy on the module hand side, as this requires 3 lines of code for each constant, and I think 5 times the constant name. Very boring to write that for a list of names. But this code could be easily generated using some scripting language.