# Can a preprocessing token be shielded from expansion?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Suppose we have a macro defined:

```
#define FOO 42
```

Is it possible to define a macro

```
#define SHIELD(x) // <- your code here
```

such that

```
SHIELD(FOO)
```

expands to `FOO` and not to `42`?

Comment: I think it is not possible.

Comment: Re “Is it possible…”: Yes, simply define the macro in a different translation unit. Otherwise, no. C 2018 6.10.3 specifies macro replacement. Unless an argument is being operated on with `#` or `##`, it is macro-replaced as if it formed the rest of the file, i.e., for `SHIELD(FOO)`, if `FOO` were the rest of the file, it would be replaced by `42`, and then further macro processing continues. There is no opportunity in this to prevent `FOO` from being replaced.

Comment: What is FOO to be if not the token that was defined? Why does FOO need to appear and then be "shielded" (disappear)...

Comment: @Fe2O3 for example in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75043279/exporting-constant-macros-as-constexpr-values-in-c20-module) scenario.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was hoping it could be done with some clever usage of `#`.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you. I think I begin to understand. `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address your question directly, but assuming you want to be able to use `FOO` in some other way after it's been defined and then reinstate the original definition, the only trick I can think of takes advantage of the `push_macro` pragma, which is supported by MSVC and possibly GCC but I'd recommend to verify that.

```
#define FOO 42
#pragma push_macro("FOO")
#undef FOO

// some stuff involving FOO

#pragma pop_macro("FOO")
```

I don't know if this helps in the particular scenario you have at hand, but it's worth knowing such a possibility exists.

**EDIT**: as kindly reported by @Jonathan Leffler, GCC documents support for the pragma in question in the 12.2.0 documentation at [Push/Pop Macro Pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Push_002fPop-Macro-Pragmas.html#Push_002fPop-Macro-Pragmas). It was there in earlier versions too

Comment: I was hoping it can be done without that much boilerplate.

Comment: @n.m. I feel ya. I just posted it to make sure the option doesn’t go unnoticed but yeah, not really a lean option…

Comment: FYI: GCC documents it in the 12.2.0 documentation at [Push/Pop Macro Pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Push_002fPop-Macro-Pragmas.html#Push_002fPop-Macro-Pragmas).  It was there in earlier versions too.