# Windows.h in Clang c++20 modules

Tags: c++, windows, module, clang, c++20

I started working on my first project using c++20 modules, and i chose LLVM Clang as toolset for building. Problem is that, when i try to include windows.h file, clangs acts as if i didn't. (This happens ONLY if i have import in the same translation unit)

```cpp
module;

#include <windows.h>

export module SomeModule;

import Whatever;

export HWND Something(){...}
```

In this case, whatever uses Windows.h functionality, throws errors, that symbols do not exist.
Example:

```
error: missing '#include <windef.h>'; 'HWND' must be declared before it is used
    HWND hwnd;
    ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\windef.h:39:28: note: declaration here is not visible
DECLARE_HANDLE            (HWND);
```

Why? How to make it work? Help please. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've not used modules but don't you need to export `HWND` somewhere?

Comment: @AlanBirtles no, because include directive is in the same unit, as code, that needs it.

Comment: What happens if you include `<windef.h>` directly?

Comment: @Quimby same error,  nothing changes

Comment: according to wikipedia Clang as only partial support for c++20:
"Clang has partial C++20 support that can be enabled with the option -std=c++20 (version 10 and later) or -std=c++2a (version 9 and earlier)."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20

Comment: @PatrickCharronMorneau I know that wikipedia is the font of all knowledge but in this case more specialist and detailed information is available https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support (it does show that modules implementation isn't complete in clang) as does clang's own docs: https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx20

Comment: @PatrickCharronMorneau I checked it just now, if i isolate from my main project and compile same partition module, without using my build tool, it works correct. It works, im just doing something wrong.

Comment: you isolate what from your main project ?
what other build tool are you using ?

Comment: @PatrickCharronMorneau I found something. I use my custom buildtool, that scans project and calls clang, linkers, etc, etc and builds project step by step. Thing is that, if i ever use import in same translation unit as #include <windows.h>, windows's API becomes hidden and i can't access it. If i remove all imports, everything works just fine.

Comment: @SasisaPlay: "*I use my custom buildtool*" Since you have a custom build tool, you should probably show the command line your tool is building this file with.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently able to build a `Windows` C++20 module, for Visual Studio 2022 17.5 (I didn't check any other compiler), that can be imported in our company code base. In all C++ source files needing Windows API, I then put `import Windows;` instead of the traditional `#include <Windows.h>`. Note that this approach requires to use the full names of API functions like `CreateFileW`, not the traditional macro version `CreateFile`, since in modules macros are never exported. I see this as an advantage, not polluting the client code with hidden macro definitions that can sometimes create weird compilation errors.

The module definition is a bit of a hack, but seems to work. Here is an abbreviated version, but you get the idea:

```
module;

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define static // I know it is UB, but it works...

export module Windows;
#pragma warning(disable: 5244)
export
{
#define MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_WINBASE_H_DEFINE_INTERLOCKED_CPLUSPLUS_OVERLOADS 0
    // Windows declarations here
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
}
#include "Windows.macro.h"
```

The *undefined behavior* `#define static` was necessary because in some places of Windows API, some C functions are exported as `__inline static`, and this is not compatible with `export`.

The `Windows.macro.h` header is a generated file from a simple list of macro names to export in a text file. I did not export all macro names (there are tons of them), but only the ones we actually use. The header looks like that:

```
const auto TEMP_MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE = MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE;
#undef MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE
export const auto MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE = TEMP_MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE;

const auto TEMP_MB_ICONSTOP = MB_ICONSTOP;
#undef MB_ICONSTOP
export const auto MB_ICONSTOP = TEMP_MB_ICONSTOP;

const auto TEMP_DATE_SHORTDATE = DATE_SHORTDATE;
#undef DATE_SHORTDATE
export const auto DATE_SHORTDATE = TEMP_DATE_SHORTDATE;
...
```

I asked recently [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75043279) about how to export C macro constants to C++ exportable ones.