C macros overwrite C++ names
I am writing a C++ application using the TGUI library. Since I do have some special requirements on Windows so I include <windows.h> so I can pass the tgui native window handler.
However, I now have an interesting problem when I want to create a tgui MessageBox using its static member function tgui::MessageBox::create(). Since MessageBox is a macro defined in windows.h as #define MessageBox MessageBoxA, I now get compilation errors...
Is there any way at all to "scope" the C-macros, or can I only refactor code to not contain both a tgui messagebox and windows.h in the same file?
Of course, the general question is: How do we safely include C-headers with various macros in C++? can we even?

Is tgui::MessageBox a class (or a struct, as opposed to a nested namespace)?

The question you actually asked is covered by Setting the scope of a MACRO and Limit the scope of #include <windows.h> (no, the preprocessor knows no scopes). Perhaps you would prefer to instead ask for work-arounds?

To answer your question about scoping macros, it's not possible. Macros are global, and might be expanded even without the actual C++ compiler running.

Possible (flaky) workaround : You could try to include windows before your header file and then #undef MessageBox. (WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN does not seem to exclude the part that defines MessageBox).

I see this as no different than all of the issues with windows.h having min, and max being macros, and interfering with std::min and std::max.  If you know the source file is going to use tgui::MessageBox you could try #undef MessageBox after you include windows.h

@3CxEZiVlQ how does (tgui::MessageBox::create)() work? I cant compile that on Windows with cl. I get the same issue as before

@JaMiT tgui is a namespace, and MessageBox is a class

The trick with extra parenthesis expained by @3CxEZiVlQ only works for function-like macros like min(a,b), but not for variable like ones as #define MessageBox MessageBoxW.

To me, the ideal solution to this recurrent problem would be to use C++20 modules and have a Windows module that you can import, but without macros of course since C++ modules never export macros. I tried to do something like that, as illustrated in my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75043279. In practice, current tool chains are still not ready for that, and for Windows.h we need quite some hack.

Welcome to the wild and wacky world of Windows programming.

@Noxet "tgui is a namespace, and MessageBox is a class" -- Information in comments does not count as part of a question. The reason I asked is that a namespace alias, like namespace tguiNN = tgui::NestedNamespace; does not help when the problematic name is not a namespace (but could if it was). And without clarification, the syntax A::B::foo() could be either foo() in namespace A::B or (static) foo() in class/struct B in namespace A.

MessageBox macro and corresponding functions are defined in winuser.h that is included in windows.h. The inclusion of the content of winuser.h is controlled by the macro NOUSER. Define it at the top of a file or globally in the project build settings.
#define NOUSER
#include <windows.h>

Or call TGUI functions like (tgui::MessageBox::create)(). That does not work since MessageBox is not a function-like macro MessageBox(x, y, z). Hence, #undef MessageBox after #include <windows.h> makes a trick.
Other useful definitions in a user files:
/*  If defined, the following flags inhibit definition
 *     of the indicated items.
 *
 *  NOGDICAPMASKS     - CC_*, LC_*, PC_*, CP_*, TC_*, RC_
 *  NOVIRTUALKEYCODES - VK_*
 *  NOWINMESSAGES     - WM_*, EM_*, LB_*, CB_*
 *  NOWINSTYLES       - WS_*, CS_*, ES_*, LBS_*, SBS_*, CBS_*
 *  NOSYSMETRICS      - SM_*
 *  NOMENUS           - MF_*
 *  NOICONS           - IDI_*
 *  NOKEYSTATES       - MK_*
 *  NOSYSCOMMANDS     - SC_*
 *  NORASTEROPS       - Binary and Tertiary raster ops
 *  NOSHOWWINDOW      - SW_*
 *  OEMRESOURCE       - OEM Resource values
 *  NOATOM            - Atom Manager routines
 *  NOCLIPBOARD       - Clipboard routines
 *  NOCOLOR           - Screen colors
 *  NOCTLMGR          - Control and Dialog routines
 *  NODRAWTEXT        - DrawText() and DT_*
 *  NOGDI             - All GDI defines and routines
 *  NOKERNEL          - All KERNEL defines and routines
 *  NOUSER            - All USER defines and routines
 *  NONLS             - All NLS defines and routines
 *  NOMB              - MB_* and MessageBox()
 *  NOMEMMGR          - GMEM_*, LMEM_*, GHND, LHND, associated routines
 *  NOMETAFILE        - typedef METAFILEPICT
 *  NOMINMAX          - Macros min(a,b) and max(a,b)
 *  NOMSG             - typedef MSG and associated routines
 *  NOOPENFILE        - OpenFile(), OemToAnsi, AnsiToOem, and OF_*
 *  NOSCROLL          - SB_* and scrolling routines
 *  NOSERVICE         - All Service Controller routines, SERVICE_ equates, etc.
 *  NOSOUND           - Sound driver routines
 *  NOTEXTMETRIC      - typedef TEXTMETRIC and associated routines
 *  NOWH              - SetWindowsHook and WH_*
 *  NOWINOFFSETS      - GWL_*, GCL_*, associated routines
 *  NOCOMM            - COMM driver routines
 *  NOKANJI           - Kanji support stuff.
 *  NOHELP            - Help engine interface.
 *  NOPROFILER        - Profiler interface.
 *  NODEFERWINDOWPOS  - DeferWindowPos routines
 *  NOMCX             - Modem Configuration Extensions
 */



I do have some special requirements.

By the way you unlikely need #include <windows.h>, I'm pretty sure these requirements are satisfied by
#include <windef.h>

or even by
#include <minwindef.h>

or
#include <windef.h>
#include <winbase.h>


The complete list of the inclusions is below. You can include only what you need. You don't need #include <winuser.h> definitely.
#include <windef.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <wingdi.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#if !defined(_MAC) || defined(_WIN32NLS)
#include <winnls.h>
#endif
#ifndef _MAC
#include <wincon.h>
#include <winver.h>
#endif
#if !defined(_MAC) || defined(_WIN32REG)
#include <winreg.h>
#endif
#ifndef _MAC
#include <winnetwk.h>
#endif

#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <cderr.h>
#include <dde.h>
#include <ddeml.h>
#include <dlgs.h>
#ifndef _MAC
#include <lzexpand.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <nb30.h>
#include <rpc.h>
#endif
#include <shellapi.h>
#ifndef _MAC
#include <winperf.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#endif
#ifndef NOCRYPT
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <winefs.h>
#include <winscard.h>
#endif

#ifndef NOGDI
#ifndef _MAC
#include <winspool.h>
#ifdef INC_OLE1
#include <ole.h>
#else
#include <ole2.h>
#endif /* !INC_OLE1 */
#endif /* !MAC */
#include <commdlg.h>
#endif /* !NOGDI */
#endif /* WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN */

#include <stralign.h>

#ifdef _MAC
#include <winwlm.h>
#endif


#ifdef INC_OLE2
#include <ole2.h>
#endif /* INC_OLE2 */

#ifndef _MAC
#ifndef NOSERVICE
#include <winsvc.h>
#endif

#if(WINVER >= 0x0400)
#ifndef NOMCX
#include <mcx.h>
#endif /* NOMCX */

#ifndef NOIME
#include <imm.h>
#endif
#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0400 */
#endif

You can see above yet another useful macro preventing many inclusions: WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN.

Thank you for the detailed answer. I tried the #define NOUSER but I get a lot of other errors, such as C2061, C3646, and C2146.
I do need the ShowWindow function, which is defined in WinUser.h
The #undef worked like a charm, so I'll go with that for now!

"call TGUI functions like (tgui::MessageBox::create)()" parenthesis can indeed block MACRO-function, but it is not the case here...
